# Wait for kernel execution on different platform

Tags: opencl

I am currently trying to get familiar with heterogeneous programming using OpenCL and have a hard time understanding how to integrate devices from different platforms.

In the below example I try to execute dependent kernels on different devices/platforms. However, I don't know how to synchronize these kernels without fully interrupting the execution. In my example structure I want to execute a kernel on the CPU (`src_node`) and process the output in parallel using CPU (`CPU_child`) and GPU (`GPU_child`) in parallel.

How do I make sure that `GPU_child` isn't executed before finishing `src_node` without interrupting the execution of `CPU_child`?

As far as I understood, events are only valid within one context and it is impossible to create a shared context with devices from different platforms. I found it difficult to find any information online about systems with different platforms. Is this actually uncommon? Am I doing something wrong?

```
... 

cl::Device CPU = ...;
cl::Device GPU = ...;
std::string kernel = ...;

cl::Context CPU_context = cl::Context({CPU});
cl::Context GPU_context = cl::Context({GPU});

cl::CommandQueue CPU_queue(CPU_context, CPU);
cl::CommandQueue GPU_queue(GPU_context, GPU);

cl::Program CPU_program(CPU_context, {kernel});
cl::Program GPU_program(GPU_context, {kernel});

CPU_program.build({CPU});
GPU_program.build({GPU});

cl::Kernel src_node(CPU_program, "kernel");
cl::Kernel CPU_child(CPU_program, "kernel");
cl::Kernel GPU_child(GPU_program, "kernel");

const int N = 10e6;
std::vector<unsigned> input(N, 1);
std::vector<unsigned> immediate(N);

cl::Buffer input_buffer(CPU_context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, N * sizeof(unsigned), input.data());
cl::Buffer immediate_buffer(CPU_context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, N * sizeof(unsigned), immediate.data());
cl::Buffer output_buffer(CPU_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N * sizeof(unsigned));

cl::Buffer immediate_buffer_GPU(GPU_context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, N * sizeof(unsigned), immediate.data());
cl::Buffer output_buffer_GPU(GPU_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, N * sizeof(unsigned));

src_node.setArg(0, input_buffer);
src_node.setArg(1, immediate_buffer);

CPU_child.setArg(0, immediate_buffer);
CPU_child.setArg(1, output_buffer);

GPU_child.setArg(0, immediate_buffer_GPU);
GPU_child.setArg(1, output_buffer_GPU);

std::vector<cl::Event> events = { cl::Event() };
CPU_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(src_node, cl::NullRange, N, cl::NullRange, NULL, &events[0]);

// This works
CPU_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(CPU_child, cl::NullRange, N, cl::NullRange, &events);

// This does not work, how to do this?
GPU_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(GPU_child, cl::NullRange, N, cl::NullRange, &events);

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems I can spot with this code:

- `immediate_buffer_GPU` is filled with the contents of `immediate` before `src_node` has even had a chance to populate it with its output via `immediate_buffer`.
- You are attempting to mix event objects from different contexts. This won't work.

As far as I'm aware, if the devices aren't from matching platforms, and therefore can't be used from a single context, you'll have to perform all synchronisation "the hard way:" you'll need to explicitly wait for events to complete in the one context before enqueueing dependent operations (including copying a buffer) on another context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on the "hard way"? Suppose I have a large graph of different tasks that should be executed partly on CPU and partly on GPU. Since I don't know before when a task will be finished I would have to keep track of all potential events in different host threads? This seems quite cumbersome/inefficient.

Comment: It can be, but you may want to check if your platform has any additional support for synchronising with host threads and tasks. For example, [on macOS, there are some interoperability APIs for combining OpenCL with GCD/libdispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/UsingGCDwOpenCL/UsingGCDwOpenCL.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH13-SW1). (Though OpenCL itself is deprecated on macOS, so if you're targeting that platform, use Metal compute shaders.) I don't know if there's anything similar for other OSes.